# in spring 3.1 why security:authentication-provider is not allowed in security:authentication-manager?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I I am trying to use spring security to control authentication in my RMI client app.

I am using maven to load 3.1.3.RELEASE spring

Then in my client xml, I am seeing "authentication-provider is not allowed here" message.

This is the spring xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
">

<bean id="employeeService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1234/employee-service"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="rmi.common.EmployeeService"/>
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="remoteInvocationFactory"><ref bean="remoteInvocationFactory"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="remoteInvocationFactory" class="org.springframework.security.remoting.rmi.ContextPropagatingRemoteInvocationFactory"/>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="rmi.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
</beans>
```

This is my client side code:
package rmi.client;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import rmi.common.Employee;
import rmi.common.EmployeeService;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeClient {

@Resource(name = "authManager")
private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; // specific for Spring Security

private  static ApplicationContext ctx;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rmi-client-context.xml");
    new EmployeeClient().exec();
}
public void exec() {
    EmployeeService employee = (EmployeeService) ctx.getBean("employeeService");


    Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("myuser", "mypwd"));

    if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
    }

        employee.addEmployee(new Employee("Jack Su", "address1"));
        employee.addEmployee(new Employee("Alice Liu", "address2"));
        List<Employee> employees = employee.getEmployees();
        System.out.println("Total number of employees: " + employees.size());
        Iterator<Employee> it = employees.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) it.next();
            System.out.println(" " + emp);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my testing authentication provider:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication argAuth) throws AuthenticationException {



        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(argAuth.getPrincipal(),
                argAuth.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
        auth.setAuthenticated(true);
        return auth;

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact error, but something in your configuration might be wrong.
Your EmployeeClient is not a Spring-Managed-Bean, because you created it with new-operator, so your `@Resource(name = "authManager")` should not work. If you posted all your configuration `authenticationManager.authenticate(..)` should produce NullPointerException.

Instead of new you could do this in your Main.

```
   EmployeeClient client = (EmployeeClient) ctx.getBean("employeeClient");
   client.exec();
```

(and add @Service to your EmployeeClient).